# how to automate pbrun su - command via plink

Tags: shell, ssh, putty, plink

I am trying to automate sFTP process for our project. When I login with putty tool and manully type the command pbrun su - user1, the root access is given to the user1 and I am able to do the sFTP process.

I want to perform the same process via plink(command line version of putty). But when I type plink -pw password user1@server pbrun su - user1 in the command prompt, the root access is not given to the user1 and error(chown : no file or directory found)is displayed. I am wondering when I type the same command manually via putty no error is displayed but when I send the same command via plink it does not work.

Plz tell me is there any config setup need to done at the powerbroker to automate pbrun su - command. Thanks in advance.

Note : I am able to run all other unix commands except pbrun su - via plink.